# How to design a table like this

Tags: html, css, html-table

How to design a table like the examples below? In the image 
vertical text alignment till specified columns;
is this design possible?

[image]

I have added it in fiddle, and used bootstrap and CSS style.

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th colspan="3" style="background-color: rgb(252, 219, 21);">
        <img src="academic year 20.png" class="img-responsive" style="width: 10%;float:left;vertical-align:middle;margin-right: 35px; " />
        <h3 style="vertical-align:middle;margin-top:30px;">text sample</h3>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="fnt">text</td>
      <td class="prpl">texttexttexttext 1</td>
      <td class="prpl">texttext 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="fnt">text </td>
      <td class="ctr">-</td>
      <td class="ctr">-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="fnt">text</td>
      <td class="ctr">-</td>
      <td class="ctr">-</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[Attached fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prabashanash/89m7vq9s/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this cord...

```
<table border ="1">
    <tr>
    <td colspan ="5">Text</td>
    <tr>
    <td colspan ="3"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td rowspan ="6"></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td rowspan ="5"></td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td rowspan ="3"></td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>13</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>14</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

use this css for appear in beautiful.

```
td{
padding : 10px;
margin : 3px;
width : 200px;
height : 100px;
}
```

This is the basic css. Customized it as you wish.